# Is it secure to make a seperate project which checks whether a license is active

Tags: c#, licensing, wpf

I am trying to make a project which will help me to implement feature based licensing in future projects. The projects in this solution are C#/WPF Projects.

So I have a Helper-Project with a class **"Licensing"** which contains the following function:

```
public bool CheckLicenseForFeatureId(int featureId) {
   // return true/false
}
```

I am adding a reference to this project and call this function on start of the project in the constructor of **App.xaml**

```
public App() {
   Licensing.CheckLicenseForFeatureId(10);
}
```

The debug folder now looks like this:

[image]

My Question: Is there a security problem when using functions of a different project in order to check if a software is licensed properly?

Comment: It's pretty trivial to replace the DLLs if the user turns off strong name validation.

Comment: How 'secure' do you need?

Comment: If your executable is in my computer and the security boils down to an `if` somewhere, to bypass it, all I need to do is to find the conditional jump and flip it. And the fact that this is .NET would make that much more easier. So, don't worry about it.

Comment: @Theraot So you mean it is not secure like that? What could I make better?

Comment: @user1937198 The user should not be able to bypass this mechanic (or as hard as possible). Is it possible to just replace the .exe with a custom one which always returns true?

Comment: Define "better", how good is enough? Messing with a .NET assembly is easy. Putting the security checks in another assembly is about the same. If it was good enough for you when it was in the same assembly, it should be good enough for you in a different one. You can, of course, make it harder. You can try obfuscation, hash and decrypt, and so on. And I'd probably desist. But somebody with the monetary incentive probably won't. If it is in the computer of the user, and the user is determined to access it, you can only make it hard, never impossible. And that can make cloud computing attractive.

Comment: @Theraot Yeah i know about obfuscation and so on and I also have a tool for this which also will be applied but that's not my question. Do mean there is no difference in security if I put the code in a different project or in the same and no difference when using 2 rather than 1 .exe Files in the delivered software?

Comment: @Updater Well, there is a difference. If I have to find, in an assembly, where to edit to bypass its security, I will have a harder job in a larger assembly. But that is no excuse to not use another project. Good obfuscation tools can merge two assemblies and then obfuscate them. If that is not available to you… You can have external source files in your project, so that your projects share them. Or use git submodules. Or make your second project a Source Code Only NuGet Package (and host it in a private Nuget server), every time you add it, it would copy the source into your project.